# Finding thinnest conductive non-magnetic material

Tags: material-science, electromagnetic-induction

I want to find the thinnest possible material, so it let's trough most of the 30 kHz magnetic field, but is also good for use as a terminal for an "air" capacitor. The material should have the highest as possible permitivity so that the capacitance is as big as possible and as low as possible magnetic permeability so that the eddy losses are small as possible because of reduced skin effect.

I need a material sheet or spray to then make as small as possible layer (order of one micron). What material to use and where to actually get it. It would be best to be easily obtainable. This is going to be used in the end in mass production so the focus should be on price as well. But for now it's just for predevelopment.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You might find more useful help at the Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange.

Comment: 1. In a capacitor, you don't worry about the permittivity of the plate material, you worry about the permittivity of the dielectric between the plates. 2. You can sputter or evaporate metals onto many surfaces with thicknesses down to nanometers. Start at the wiki page for [thin films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_film).

Comment: I have no controll over permittivity of the dielectric because it is random in my case, what the user puts on. Thank you for the second part of sugestion, but I hope it is not difficult to make.